# React Filling ButtonGroup with Buttons using an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to fill a ButtonGroup with Buttons using array.map(), but the buttons aren't showing up. I used the exact same method to fill a DropdownButton with MenuItems no problem.

The working DropdownButton is here:

```
<DropdownButton title={this.state.regionallevel} onSelect={(evt)=>{
                this.setState({regionallevel: evt}, () => {
                    this.sendNewScenarios();
                })}}>
                {regionalLevels.map((regionalleveli, i) =>
                    <MenuItem eventKey={regionalleveli} key={i}>{regionalleveli}</MenuItem>)}
            </DropdownButton>
```

And here is the non-working ButtonGroup:

```
<ButtonGroup vertical>
                {scenarios.map=((scenarioi, i) =>
                    <Button color="default" key={i} onClick={() => this.onCheckboxBtnClick(scenarioi)} active={this.state.checkboxesSelected.includes(scenarioi)}>{scenarioi}</Button>)}
            </ButtonGroup>
```

The ButtonGroup does work if I do it like this, but I need it to be dynamic:

```
<ButtonGroup vertical>
                <Button color="default" onClick={() => this.onCheckboxBtnClick(scenarios[0])} active={this.state.checkboxesSelected.includes(scenarios[0])}>{scenarios[0]}</Button>
                <Button color="default" onClick={() => this.onCheckboxBtnClick(scenarios[1])} active={this.state.checkboxesSelected.includes(scenarios[1])}>{scenarios[1]}</Button>
                <Button color="default" onClick={() => this.onCheckboxBtnClick(scenarios[2])} active={this.state.checkboxesSelected.includes(scenarios[2])}>{scenarios[2]}</Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
```

The components are imported from react-bootstrap. Where could the problem be?

UPDATE: Ok, I'm not sure why, but the ButtonGroup works properly now, even though I didn't change the code at all. But there's another ButtonGroup that should work the same way, but doesn't. Here's the code:

```
<ButtonGroup vertical>
                {periods.map=((periodi, i) =>
                    <Button color="default" key={i} onClick={() => this.onRadioBtnClick(periodi)} active={this.state.radioButtonSelected===periodi}>{periodi}</Button>)}
            </ButtonGroup>
```

And here's what the console shows. Line 95 is where the ButtonGroup above starts:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
in div (created by ButtonGroup)
in ButtonGroup (at DropdownMenuScenarios.js:95)
in div (at DropdownMenuScenarios.js:56)
in DropdownMenuScenarios (at App.js:36)
in div (at App.js:29)
in App (at index.js:7)
```

Comment: can you report the error that console shows ?

Comment: I updated the OP.

Comment: I will answer now @akuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo ( an extra `=`) . So :

```
 periods.map((periodi, i) => ....
```

and not

```
 periods.map=((periodi, i) => ...
```

And that's why the error was clear : `Functions are not valid as a React child.`

Comment: Oh, so I did change the code at some point. Thanks, it's embarassing I didn't notice that!

Comment: Welcome @akuj 